# Tracking tweet in realtime with tracking terms changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I want to build an application that allow users to set a hashtags or mentions that they want to track from their dashboard, and my api will open a web socket to display the tweets in realtime at client side.

If I use twitter streaming api, I need to close and reopen the connection every time user change or add a tracking term. This seems not good, and not scale well.

Is there a better approach for this problem? Please advise.